# EU citizen traveling with non-EU spouse (with residence permit in EU) to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, eu-citizens, italian-residents

My mum and dad are planning on visiting my sister in the UK. My dad is an EU citizen but my mom is not. She does have a residence permit in Italy though (I think it's called permesso di soggiorno).

I've read about EU citizens being able to travel with their non-EU spouses if they have an article 10 residence permit (see link below) so I wanted to ask if her residence card qualifies as an article 10 permit and if she can travel with my dad without having to apply for a visa?

[Link to home office website on Article 10 residence permit](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card#evidence-you-need-to-bring-in-addition-to-your-residence-card)

Comment: You have to check exactly what type of Permesso di soggiorno she has. Is it per motivi familiari?

Comment: @gstorto I've just received a photo of her residence permit and it says 'tipo di permesso di soggiorno: soggiornante di lungo periodo'.